# Is there any way to Read/Write RFID Tags in React.JS?

Tags: reactjs, tags, nfc, rfid

I'm trying to build a web application using reactjs that dealing with RFID tags.
is there any way to do that for a web app? any helping packages.

I fond React Native packages but no one for ReactJS

Comment: I found some results for React Native, i need it for React Js if its available

Comment: Since JavaScript runs in a Browser and the browser does not have any rights to access programms outsite of the Browser-Scope:  No. You may want to write windows-service which communicates with the hardware and JS communicates via WebSocket or Rest with this service.